# Storing an XML element in a string

Tags: xml, swift

I am using the SWXMLHash to parse a XML webpage

```
let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)
println(xml["root"]["schedule"]["date"].element?.text)
```

This successfully prints out the element I want. However, I cannot seem to store it in a string.

I declare the string

```
var getXmlItem: String
```

And I try to set it equal to the XML element I want:

```
getXmlItem = xml["root"]["schedule"]["date"].element?.text
```

But this gives me the error:

> Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Is this not the way to set it equal to the XML? I am still learning Swift so this is confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Swift takes a hardline between values that can be null and values that cannot be null. I think`text` is optional within the SWXMLHash framrwork. Try this:

```
getXmlItem = xml["root"]["schedule"]["date"].element?.text!
```

You need to be sure that `text` isn't a nil though.

An alternative is to declare `getXmlItem` as an optional string:

```
var getXmlItem : String?
```

What I prefer is for Swift to infer type automatically:

```
var getXmlItem = xml["root"]["schedule"]["date"].element?.text
// getXmlItem is now String?
```